# Tradingview Chart Extraction with Javascript - Puppeteer - Node.js - Web Scraping

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I would like to extract the image of my TradingView chart with the dark theme and my indicator.

Currently, with Puppeteer, I can only perform the extraction of the chart without any customizations:

[image: like this].

I have seen several signal rooms that have it, so theoretically, it is possible to do it.

My bot is written in JavaScript and executed with Node.js.

```
async function captureChartScreenshot(symbol, interval) {
    let chromiumPath;
    if (os.platform() === 'win32') {
        chromiumPath = mypath
        console.log('Running on Windows, using Chromium path:', chromiumPath);
    }
    else if (os.platform() === 'linux') {
        chromiumPath = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'; // Assicurati che questo sia il percorso corretto per Chromium sul tuo Raspberry Pi
        console.log('Running on Linux, using Chromium path:', chromiumPath);
    }

    console.log('Launching browser...');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: 'new',
        executablePath: chromiumPath,
    });
    console.log('Browser launched');

    try {
        console.log('Opening new page...');
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log('New page opened');

        const chartUrl = `https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=${symbol}&interval=${interval}`;
        console.log('Going to URL:', chartUrl);
        await page.goto(chartUrl);
        console.log('Arrived at URL:', page.url());

        console.log('Waiting for chart to load...');
        await page.waitForSelector('.chart-gui-wrapper');
        console.log('Chart loaded');

        console.log('Setting viewport...');
        await page.setViewport({
            width: 480,
            height: 480,
        });
        console.log('Viewport set');

        console.log('Selecting chart element...');
        const graficoElement = await page.$('.chart-container');
        console.log('Chart element selected');

        console.log('Getting chart bounding box...');
        const graficoBoundingBox = await graficoElement.boundingBox();
        console.log('Chart bounding box:', graficoBoundingBox);

        console.log('Taking screenshot...');
        const screenshotBuffer = await graficoElement.screenshot({
            clip: {
                x: graficoBoundingBox.x,
                y: graficoBoundingBox.y,
                width: Math.min(graficoBoundingBox.width, page.viewport().width),
                height: Math.min(graficoBoundingBox.height, page.viewport().height),
            },
        });
        console.log('Screenshot taken');

        console.log('Closing browser...');
        await browser.close();
        console.log('Browser closed');

        return screenshotBuffer;
    } catch (error) {
        const timestamp = new Date().toLocaleString();
        const errorLine = error.stack.split('\n')[1].trim(); // Ottieni la riga dell'errore dalla traccia dello stack
        console.error(`${timestamp} - ${__filename} - Errore alla riga: ${errorLine}\n${error}`);
        return;
    }
}
```

Therefore, my expectation is for the bot to take the chart containing my indicator and send it to me:

[image: Expectation]

20230724 Update:

I tried to update the browser launching on this way and inserted log, with timeout for execution, but it won't function:

```
console.log('Launching browser...');
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: 'new',
    executablePath: chromiumPath,
    slowMo: os.platform() === 'linux' ? 60000 : 0, // Aggiungi un ritardo di 30 secondi (30000 ms) solo per Linux
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-gpu'] // Aggiungi le opzioni --no-sandbox e --disable-dev-shm-usage
});

console.log(browser);
```

Comment: have you done this? I need the same thing

Answer (score 0):

To switch to DarkMode you can add param `theme=dark` on the Url

```
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=${symbol}&interval=${interval}&theme=dark
```